# Nested index route not rendering in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a create-react-app project with react-router-dom v6 installed. Trying to use the new index route syntax so that my HomePage component renders at the index that is currently serving a Layout component. When I navigate to the index (http://localhost:3000/), it renders the Layout component with site name in an  but not the HomePage component (The "Home Page"  does not render).

Thanks for the help!

Code below:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {Routes, Route, Outlet, Link, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout";
import HomePage from "./pages/Home";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
        <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

Layout.js

```
import data from "../../config/siteconfig.json"

const settings = data.settings;

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{settings.sitename}</h1>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: why dont u just add homepage and layout in 1 component ? or I'm not understanding right otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedSalah. Trying to follow the docs on the new router version and that's how they have the example set up in the docs. I like the idea of having the routes nested and wanted to try it out. Following the docs exactly but no rendering of the HomePage component. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want nested `Route` components to render then the `Layout` component should render an `Outlet` for them to be rendered into. Using `children` prop would be if `Layout` was ***directly*** wrapping children components.

In other words, it is the difference between

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={(
    <Layout>
      <HomePage /> // <-- rendered as children
    </Layout>
  )}
/>
```

and

```
<Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route index element={<HomePage />} /> // <-- rendered as nested route
</Route>
```

Suggested code update:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{settings.sitename}</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```